# Import Error:No module named rospkg

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Error (Happened after I fixed the error above and I tried to rosrun tf view_frames)

```
user@ubuntu:~$ rosrun tf view_frames 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/scripts/view_frames", line 43, in <module>
    import roslib; roslib.load_manifest(PKG) 
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from roslib.launcher import load_manifest
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in <module>
    import rospkg
ImportError: No module named rospkg
```

Solution executed: (Make no difference)
$sudo apt-get install python-rospkg
$sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-fuerte-ros-comm
reinstall python 2.7

```
user@ubuntu:~$ env | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/common-lisp/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_DISTRO=fuerte
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/fuerte/etc/ros

PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:
```

Please help I can't continue with my work, very much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86126/import-error:no-module-named-rospkg/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-10-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-03**:
What is your PYTHON_PATH?

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-03**:
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/user/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/

I just added 'export $PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/' that's it looks a little different right now, after I add it into pythonpath now my bad marshall data(string ref out of range) come back again..

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-03**:
How to set my pythonpath back to default?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-03**:
If you open a new terminal that will reset your environment back to what's in you ~/.bashrc is there anything in that? Can you share what your env is with 'env | grep ROS && env | grep PY.  Please add it as an edit of your question to get good formatting.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-04**:
What happens if you just open `python` and type `import rospkg`?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-10-05**:
What Ubuntu version are you using and what Python version?

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-06**:
I am using python 2.7, it was functioning well before. Until I edit my roslaunch file someday and trying to roslaunch it and the python seems to be crashed on that time.
@dornhege

> > > import rospkg
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > ImportError: No module named rospkg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's an odd error.

As a random guess your installation is corrupted.  I'd suggest trying
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-fuerte-ros-comm

If you want to debug it you can manually try to reproduce by running the imports manually in a python instance.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-02**:
Reinstall doesn't help. Does reinstalling python will do? How am I gonna do?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-02**:
From your update that it's failing to import rospkg. Check that you don't have a pip version of rospkg and try reinstalling python-rospkg in the same way as above.

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-02**:
I have tried sudo apt-get python-rospkg and it doesn't make any different, that's the problem right now.

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-02**:
Reinstall fuerte still can't fix the problem.

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-06**:
Bad marshal data fixed after I reboot my computer.

**Comment by [tgaaly](https://answers.ros.org/users/2200/tgaaly/) on 2013-12-07**:
I have the same problem. I cannot even import rospkg within python. rospkg is not in my /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7 directory. There are 2 rospkg_loader.* files within the rosdep2 subfolder. Im not sure whats going on but I keep getting the "ImportError: No module named rospkg" when running roscore